# Using dynamic cut() breaks for each row of a dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, python-polars

I am trying to bin values to prepare data to be later fed into a plotting library.

For this I am trying to use polars `Expr.cut`. The dataframe I operate on contains different groups of values, each of these groups should be binned using different breaks. Ideally I would like to use `np.linspace(BinMin, BinMax, 50)` for the `breaks` argument of `Expr.cut`.

I managed to make the `BinMin` and `BinMax` columns in the dataframe. But I can't manage to use `np.linspace` to define the breaks dynamically for each row of the dataframe.

This is a minimal example of what I tried:

```py
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"Value": [12], "BinMin": [0], "BinMax": [100]})
```

At this point the dataframe looks like:

```
┌───────┬────────┬────────┐
│ Value ┆ BinMin ┆ BinMax │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ i64   ┆ i64    ┆ i64    │
╞═══════╪════════╪════════╡
│ 12    ┆ 0      ┆ 100    │
└───────┴────────┴────────┘
```

And trying to use `Expr.cut` with dynamic breaks:

```
df.with_columns(pl.col("Value").cut(breaks=np.linspace(pl.col("BinMin"), pl.col("BinMax"), 50)).alias("Bin"))


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 1
----> 1 df.with_columns(pl.col("Value").cut(breaks=range(pl.col("BinMin"), pl.col("BinMax"))).alias("Bin"))

TypeError: 'Expr' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I understand the error, that `np.linspace` is expecting to be called with actual scalar integers, not polars `Expr`. But I cannot figure out how to call it with dynamic breaks derived from the `BinMin` and `BinMax` columns.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [`pl.Expr.cut`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cut.html) doesn't support expressions for the `breaks` argument (yet), but requires a fixed sequence.

(This would be a good feature request though).

A naive solution that will work for DataFrames, but doesn't use polars' native expression API, would be to use [`pl.Expr.map_elements`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.map_elements.html) together with the corresponding functionality in numpy.

```py
def my_cut(x, num=50):
    seq = np.linspace(x["BinMin"], x["BinMax"], num=num)
    idx = np.digitize(x["Value"], seq)
    return seq[idx-1:idx+1].tolist()

(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.struct("Value", "BinMin", "BinMax").map_elements(my_cut).alias("Bin")
    )
)
```

```
shape: (1, 4)
┌───────┬────────┬────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ Value ┆ BinMin ┆ BinMax ┆ Bin                    │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---                    │
│ i64   ┆ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ list[f64]              │
╞═══════╪════════╪════════╪════════════════════════╡
│ 12    ┆ 0      ┆ 100    ┆ [10.204082, 12.244898] │
└───────┴────────┴────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reproduce `np.linspace` with `pl.arange` and some math.

Observe that linspace is giving you intervals of `(max-min)/(n-1)`

Then it's just this

```
df.with_columns(
    linspace=(
        pl.col("BinMin")+pl.arange(0,(n:=50))*(pl.col("BinMax")-pl.col("BinMin"))/(n-1)
        ).implode()
)
```

But of course you don't want the bins like that, you want to know which Bin that Value is in. For that, we can use the walrus operator and then sort the bins themselves by the absolute value of their difference the the Value so that the first two are the ones you want and then just take those 2.

Here's the whole thing...

```
df.with_columns(
    Bin = (
        Bins:=(
            pl.col("BinMin")+
            pl.arange(0,(n:=50))*(pl.col("BinMax")-pl.col("BinMin"))/(n-1)
            )
        )
    .sort_by((pl.col("Value")-Bins).abs())
    .implode()
    .list.gather([0,1])
    .list.reverse()
)
```

#### TL/DR start here

But of course that's unwieldy so let's put it in a function and monkey patch it so it's useable.

```
def exprcut(self, _min, _max, n):
    if isinstance(_min, str):
        _min=pl.col(_min)
    if isinstance(_max, str):
        _max=pl.col(_max)        
    return (
        Bins:=(_min+pl.arange(0,n)*(_max-_min)/(n-1))
        ).sort_by((self-Bins).abs()
                  ).implode().list.gather([0,1]).list.reverse()
pl.Expr.exprcut=exprcut
```

Now we can just do

```
df.with_columns(Bin=pl.col("Value").exprcut("BinMin", "BinMax",50))
shape: (1, 4)
┌───────┬────────┬────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ Value ┆ BinMin ┆ BinMax ┆ Bin                    │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---                    │
│ i64   ┆ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ list[f64]              │
╞═══════╪════════╪════════╪════════════════════════╡
│ 12    ┆ 0      ┆ 100    ┆ [10.204082, 12.244898] │
└───────┴────────┴────────┴────────────────────────┘
```